# Tunnel router's outbound traffic through ssh?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Not looking for VPN. Trying to bypass traffic counter by tunneling to a m/c (non-restricted  non-counted with no root access). Currently I am doing a tunnel(via sshuttle/tunnelier) for every client on my Lan. Was looking to do that on a linux Enabled router(linksys wrt300n v1.1 with possibly DD-wrt maega).

sshuttle: to circumvent apps that doesn't honor socks on mac namely flash.
tunnelier: ssh client + ssh connection watchdog for windows.

Comment: Only tcp is fine.